# Notifications API onclose event not firing

Tags: reactjs, notifications

I am trying to kick off some behavior within our application from a notification that is created using the Notification API.  I doing this with some success, but we need the same behavior whether the user clicks the notification or closes the notification by clicking the X and for whatever reason the onclose event does not fire regardless of browser.  This is a react application and the code looks something like this:

```
`async function showNotification() {
    if (Notification.permission !== "granted") {
        await Notification.requestPermission()
    }

    if (Notification.permission === "granted") { 
        const notification = new Notification('New Camera Alerts', { 
            body: 'There are new notifications to review in the Notification Panel', 
            icon: `${logo}`, 
            requireInteraction: true // this makes the dialog stay open until someone clicks it 
        }) 

        const testEvent = (event: Event) => { 
            event.preventDefault() 
            // more lines of code here with what should happen when the 
            // notification is clicked/closed 
        }

        notification.onclick = (event) => testEvent (event) 
        notification.onclose = (event) => testEvent (event) 
    } 

}`
```

What I tried is assigning the same function call to both the click and close handlers.  I was expecting both actions to have the same behavior.  What actually happens is the close event is never fired at all.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with native Notification. `close` event is triggered only when clicked on "close" button for closing notification, but not triggered when hide notification with cross (x) in right corner, hide by timeout (native is about 6s), or swipe notification (on touch screens).

Close button is normally not displayed and that's why it looks like `close` event is never triggered. So you must use special option `requireInteraction: true`. And then there will be no timeout, "close" button and functional `onclose` event :)

Example:

```js
let n = new Notification('this is my notification with close', {requireInteraction: true});
n.addEventListener('close', ()=>{
    alert('onclose event triggered!');
});
```